# Array Spread Syntax not working as expected on React State Variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-state

Hi I'm trying to take some data from my Firebase Firestore and save it to state in my React app. My code is this:

```
const [firebaseOrders, setFirebaseOrders] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const getOrders = async () => {
      
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, `users/carlos@example.com/orders`));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const newOrder = doc.data()
        setFirebaseOrders([...firebaseOrders, newOrder])
      })
  }
    getOrders();
  }, [])

  console.log(firebaseOrders)
```

I am  expecting to get an array of objects with my orders. Instead my array is not saving when I use the spread operator so I end up with just the last item in my array:

Here's a pic of what I get in the console

[image]

```
[{…}]
->0 : {titles: Array(2), timestamp: nt, prices: Array(2), amount: 869.99, amount_shipping: 6.99, …}
length : 1
->[[Prototype]] : Array(0)

[{…}]
->0 : {amount: 78.29, timestamp: nt, titles: Array(2), amount_shipping: 0, prices: Array(2), …}
length : 1
->[[Prototype]] : Array(0)
```

I feel like I am missing something basic, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying state is an asynchronous operation, so doing this in a tight loop (as you do) means that you're overwriting the previous value each time.

Instead, call `setFirebaseOrders` just once with all results:

```
setFirebaseOrders(
  querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
})
```

---

Also note that the `console.log(firebaseOrders)` may not show the correct value, as it likely runs before `setFirebaseOrders(...)` has run/completed.

If you want to see the orders from the state, show them in components in your UI. If you want to `console.log` what you get from the database, do so in the callback:

```
const orders = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
console.log(orders);
setFirebaseOrders(orders);
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation and the solution to my problem! :)